# Binary to hexadecimal and decimal in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, binary, arithmetic

I have a context where I need to convert binary to hexadecimal and decimal and viceversa in a shell script. Can someone suggest me a tool for this?

Comment: Seeing the recent answers, maybe you should specify whether “binary” means [binary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) or [binary file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file).

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280131/hexadecimal-to-decimal-in-shell-script and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378829/convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to do the conversion *from* binary in pure bash (`echo` and `printf` are builtins):

#### Binary to decimal

```
$ echo "$((2#101010101))"
341
```

#### Binary to hexadecimal

```
$ printf '%x\n' "$((2#101010101))"
155
```

Going back to binary using bash alone is somewhat more complex, so I suggest you see the other answers for solutions to that.

Comment: how about decimal to hexadecimal.

Comment: @Bangi Just do `printf '%x\n' 10`, for example.

Comment: What's the point of using `printf %d` for bin2dec? `$(( ... ))` already gives a decimal result, `echo` is enough.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - Personal preference. In general, I use `printf '%s\n' foo` instead of `echo` for a variety of reasons (mostly portability), for the same reason, I don't use it here.

Comment: @ChrisDown: I though this question was explicitly about Bash (which has a well-implemented `echo` builtin). My bad!

Comment: I don't know of any shorter way for `bash` and `ash` shells to convert numbers back into binary than to use `bc` : `printf -- 'obase=2;%d\n' "341" | bc` , however, I don't find it fast enough

Answer (score 18):

Assuming that by binary, you mean binary data as in data with any possible byte value including 0, and not base-2 numbers:

To convert **from** binary, `od` (standard), `xxd` (comes with `vim`) or `perl`'s `unpack` come to mind.

```
od -An -vtu1 # for decimal
od -An -vtx1 # for hexadecimal

xxd -p # for hexa

perl -pe 'BEGIN{$\="\n";$/=\30};$_=unpack("H*",$_)' # like xxd -p

# for decimal:
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$\="\n";$/=\30;$,=" "}; print unpack("C*",$_)'
```

Now, to convert back **to** binary, `awk` (standard), `xxd -r` or `perl`'s `pack`:

From the decimal output from `od -tu1` or `perl` above:

```
LC_ALL=C awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf "%c", $i}'
perl -ape '$_=pack("C*",@F)'
```

From the hexa `perl` or `xxd -p` above:

```
xxd -r -p
perl -pe 'chomp;$_=pack("H*",$_)'
```

Comment: xxd -r gives binary data, not ascii equivalent of hex data. ie 11111111 in binary file is FF in hex data. The question is asking to give 11111111 in ascii (displayable on screen)

Answer (score 16):

You can use bc for this by manipulating the `ibase` and `obase` parameters:

The trick is that you need to be explicit about the bases. So if your ibase is 2, then if you set your obase to 10, it won't do anything, as 10 in binary is 2. Hence you need to use hexadecimal notation.

So binary to decimal would be (watch that obase is A)

Binary to decimal:

```
$> echo 'ibase=2;obase=A;11110001011010'|bc
15450
```

Binary to hex:

```
$> echo 'ibase=2;obase=10000;11110001011010'|bc
3C5A
```

If the 'output base' `obase` is changed first, it should be easier:

```
$> echo 'obase=10;ibase=2;11110001011010'|bc
15450
$> echo 'obase=16;ibase=2;11110001011010'|bc
3C5A
```

Comment: This second example is wrong -- 'F' would be base 15, not 16 (decimal 16 in hex is 10, not F). Try `echo 'ibase=2;obase=F;1111` which *should* equal decimal 15, ie. F in hex.  It comes out as 10, which it is in base 15 (digits 0-E).  It is also easier if you state the obase *first*, eg: `echo 'obase=16;ibase=2;1111'|bc`.  No confusion.

Comment: Now it is worst. Once you set `ibase`, you have to provide input in _that_ base, even for `obase`. So in your example would be `echo 'ibase=2;obase=10000;11110001011010'|bc`. Better listen to goldilocks's advice and reverse the order – first set `obase`, then `ibase`.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean converting numbers from base-2 to 10 or 16 and back, `bc` is the standard tool to do that as already mentioned by *psarossy*.

```
decimal=123
binary=$(echo "obase=2;$decimal" | bc)
hex=$(echo "obase=16;ibase=2;$binary" | bc)
```

Some shells like `zsh` have builtin support for base conversion as part of their arithmetic expansion operators:

```
decimal=123
binary=$(([##2]decimal))
hex=$(([##16]decimal))
hex=$(([##16]2#$binary))
decimal=$((2#$binary))
```

and so on.

Both `ksh93` and `zsh` also support:

```
typeset -i2 binary=123
typeset -i16 dec2hex=123 bin2hex='2#1111'
```

But note that, when expanded, `$binary` will have a `2#` or `16#` prefix (which you can strip with `${binary#*#}`.

`ksh93` also supports:

```
printf "%..2d\n" 123
```

to convert to binary.

Comment: Some `printf` implementations allow for binary numerals: `printf '%02X' '0B1111'` can print `0F` in _some_ shells.

Comment: Usually, when converting to binary/hexadecimal, people expect the representation of the input number (i.e. without sign before the binary/hex output). For example, your `bc` solution, for a decimal input of `-1`, gives a bin/hex output of `-1`, where we could expect `111....111`/`ffff...ffff`.

Comment: @Bruno, I don't really agree. How your C compiler stores numbers as short/int/long/float/double on your computer architecture and how to get a hex dump of that is quite a different question from how to convert a number from one base to another and would be a different question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, as you want, I only said *usually*, both are valid of course... At least for me: When I ask for binary, I want to see the bits - same as `printf "%x\n"` does for hex, not something I need to convert again to see if bit 3 is set or not ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For binary to hexadecimal use: **xxd** tool in linux and for binary to decimal you can use qalculate tool.

For help regarding xxd type `xxd --help` or `man xxd` in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answer you can do Binary to Decimal and Hexa Decimal as follows in Bash using echo and printf. I am just adding here how to convert from Decimal and Hex to binary using pure Bash.

**Binary to Decimal using echo**

```
echo "$((2#101010101))"
341
```

**Binary to Hexa-Decimal using printf**

```
printf '%x\n' "$((2#101010101))"
155
```

**Integer decimal to Binary conversion using only Bash**

Using only Bash, if you would like to convert decimal to binary, you can do it like the following:

```
touch dec2bin && chmod +x "$_" && vim "$_"
```

And then copy and paste the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
## converting decimal integer to binary, pass int as a parameter
num=$1;
dec2bin()
{   [ "$num" == "" ] && { printf "Error: Pass an integer\n"; exit 1; };
    op=2; ## Since we're converting to binary
    quo=$(( $num / $op)); rem=$(( $num % $op)); ## quotient and remainder
    remarray=(); ## array for putting remainder inside array
    remarray+=("$rem"); ## array expansion
        until [[ $quo -eq 0 ]]; do
            num=$quo; quo=$(( $num / $op)); ## looping to get all remainder untill 0
            rem=$(( $num % $op)); remarray+="$rem"; ## array expansion
        done
    binary=$(echo "${remarray[@]}" | rev); ## reversing array
    printf "$binary\n"; ## printing reversed array
}
main()
{   [[ -n ${num//[0-9]/} ]] &&
        { printf "Error: $num is not an integer bruv!\n"; return 1;
        } || { dec2bin $num; }
}
main;
```

And then try it from where you saved:

```
./dec2bin 420
110100100
```

Integer must be added!!

```
./dec2bin 420.py
420.py is not an integer bruv!
```

**Hexadecimal to Binary conversion using only Bash**

Similarly, hexadecimal to binary, as follows using only bash:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
## converting hexadecimal to binary, pass hex as a parameter
hex=$1;
hex2bin()
{   [ "$hex" == "" ] && { printf "Error: Pass a hex\n"; exit 1; };
    op=2; num=$((16#$hex)); ## converting hex to integer
    quo=$(( $num/ $op)); rem=$(( $num% $op)); ## quotient and remainder
    remarray=(); remarray+=("$rem"); ## array expansion
        until [[ $quo -eq 0 ]]; do
            num=$quo; quo=$(( $num / $op)); ## looping to get all remainder untill 0
            rem=$(( $num % $op)); remarray+="$rem"; ## array expansion
        done
    binary=$(echo "${remarray[@]}" | rev); ## reversing array
    printf "$binary\n"; ## printing reversed array
}
main()
{
[[ -n ${hex//[0-9,A-F,a-f]/} ]] &&
    { printf "Error: $hex is not a hex bruv!\n"; return 1;
    } || { hex2bin $hex; }
}
main;
```

For example:

```
./hex2bin 1aF
110101111
```

Hex must be passed:

```
./hex2bin.bash XyZ
XyZ is not a hexa decimal number bruv!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP:

```
$ php -r 'printf("%b", 11);'
1011
```

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'print unpack("B*", pack("c", 11))'
00001011

$ perl -e 'print unpack("B*", pack("C", 11))'
00001011

$ perl -e 'print unpack("B*", pack("W", 11))'
00001011

$ perl -e 'print unpack("B*", pack("n", 11))'
0000000000001011

$ perl -e 'print unpack("B*", pack("N", 11))'
00000000000000000000000000001011
```