# Bash decimal to binary conversion explanation

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

When converting decimal values to their binary representation, it is possible to use the following commands:

```
val=12
D2B=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
echo ${D2B[$val]}
```

While this works, I am unable to understand or find why it does so. Would be great if someone could explain it or point me to a resource that does.

Comment: HINT: what does `echo {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}` output?

Comment: @iyiyy: It would be nice if you link to source of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) in form `{x..y}` give you all possible characters from range x to y. In this case, `{0..1}` give you `0` and `1`. Combine two pieces give you `2^2` four possible values:

```
$ printf %s\\n {0..1}{0..1}
00
01
10
11
```

Combine five pieces give you `2^5` thirty two possible values from 0 to 32 in binary form:

```
$ printf %s\\n {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}
00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
.....
11110
11111
```

Saving all values in `D2B` array, with decimal index corresponding to it binary value. Accessing index 12 `${D2B[$val]}` gave you the binary value of 12 decimal.

Actually, you can make it shorter with `{x,y}`:

```
D2B=({0,1}{0,1}{0,1}{0,1}{0,1})
```

Answer (score 2):

First, note that this is quite a memory inefficient way to do this. You might, instead, consider the answers on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65280/10762) question.

---

As for your question, though...

```
D2B=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
```

This line creates an array called `D2B` that contains all possible binary values from 00000 to 11111. Brace expansions work like this:

```
% printf '%s %s %s\n' {0..2}{0..2}{0..2} 
000 001 002
010 011 012
020 021 022
100 101 102
110 111 112
120 121 122
200 201 202
210 211 212
220 221 222
```

Due to the fact that brace expansions are expanded from the first to the last when they are adjoined, the array looks something like this:

```
00000 00001 00010 .... 11101 11110 11111
```

The indexes of these values correspond to the binary values contained within them, since here, brace expansions and the mathematic representations of numbers use the same rules.

As such, index 0 is `00000`, index 5 is `00101`, and so on. Since you pass `$val` as the index to use, the binary corresponding to your value is echoed.