# How do I print an ASCII character by different code points in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, ascii

In the ASCII table the 'J' character exists which has code points in different numeral systems:

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
112   74    4A    J
```

It's possible to print this char by an octal code point by printing
`printf '\112'` or `echo $'\112'`. How do I print the same character by decimal and hexadecimal code point presentations?

Comment: Related: [Convert binary mode to text mode and the reverse option](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205635)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hex:

```
printf '\x4a'
```

Dec:

```
printf "\\$(printf %o 74)"
```

Alternative for hex :-)

```
xxd -r <<<'0 4a'
```

Comment: Thankfully this also works in `awk`.

Answer (score 9):

In general, the shell could understand hex, oct and decimal numbers in variables, provided they have been defined as `integers`:

```
$ declare -i v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
$ v1=0112
$ v2=74
$ v3=0x4a
$ v4=8#112
$ v5=10#74
$ v6=16#4a
$ v7=18#gg
echo "$v1 $v2 $v3 $v4 $v5 $v6 $v7"
74 74 74 74 74 74 304
```

Or they are the result of an "Arithmetic Expansion":

```
$ : $(( v1=0112, v2=74, v3=0x4a, v4=8#112, v5=10#74, v6=16#4a, v7=18#gg ))
$ echo "$v1 $v2 $v3 $v4 $v5 $v6 $v7"
74 74 74 74 74 74 304
```

So, you just need one way to print the character that belongs to a variable value.
But here are two possible ways:

```
$ var=$((0x65))
$ printf '%b\n' "\\$(printf '0%o' "$var")"
e

$ declare -i var
$ var=0x65; printf '%b\n' "\U$(printf '%08x' "$var")"
e
```

The two printf are needed, one to transform the value into an hexadecimal string and the second to actually print the character.

The second one will print any UNICODE point (if your console is correctly set).
For example:

```
$ var=0x2603; printf '%b\n' "\U$(printf '%08x' "$var")"
☃
```

An snow man.

The character that has an utf-8 representation as `f0 9f 90 ae` is `0x1F42E`.
Search for `cow face site:fileformat.info` to [get it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f42e/index.htm):

```
$ var=0x1F42F; printf '%b\n' "\U$(printf '%08x' "$var")"
```

**Note**: There is a problem with the UNICODE way in that for bash before 4.3 (corrected in that version and upwards), the characters between UNICODE points 128 and 255 (in decimal) may be incorrectly printed.

---

#### References

Fourth paragraph inside `PARAMETERS` in `man bash`:

> If the variable has its integer attribute set, then value is evaluated as an arithmetic expression even if the $((...)) expansion is not used (see Arithmetic Expansion below).

Inside "ARITHMETIC EVALUATION" in `man bash`:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base#  is omitted, then base 10 is used. The digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, @, and _, in that order. If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, a codepoint is not (always) a byte value. Bash (in versions before 4.3) provides the byte value of the code point. That is: character `é` (Octal: 351, Dec: 233, Hex: 0xE9) is incorrectly printed with `printf '\351'` as it prints a byte value of `0xE9` always. For a terminal with an encoding of `ISO-8859-1` (and cousins) that may work, but in utf-8 encoded terminals, a byte value of `0xE9` should appear as �. cont....

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am [not the first to notice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F071.How_do_I_convert_an_ASCII_character_to_its_decimal_.28or_hexadecimal.29_value_and_back.3F) and search for "bash 4.2 incorrectly encodes" for one example. It has been corrected from bash 4.3 and higher.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean now (I was testing with 4.3  as per the earlier version of your answer). Note that it's only bash-4.2, bash-4.1 didn't support `\u` (which comes from zsh).

Answer (score 7):

Decimal:

```
chr() {
    local c
    for c
    do
        printf "\\$((c/64*100+c%64/8*10+c%8))"
    done
}

chr 74
```

Hex:

```js
chr $((16#4a))
```

The function can do sequences:

```
$ chr 74 75 76; echo
JKL
$
```

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`:

```
$ printf '\x4a\n' # Hex
J
$ printf "\\$(([##8]74))\n" # Dec
J
```

To get a character (in the current charset) from the Unicode code point:

```
$ printf '\U1F42E\n' # Hex

$ printf "\\U$(([##16]128046))\n" # Dec
```

The `#` parameter expansion flag combines both.

If `$var` contains an arithmetic expression (such as `0x4a`, `74`, `0x60 + 10`) whose evaluation results in a number *`n`*, then `${(#)var}` expands to the character whose byte value is *`n`* if the locale uses a single-byte character set (such as ISO8859-15, KOI8-R...), or the character of Unicode codepoint *`n`* in multi-byte character locales (or if *`n`* > 255)¹.

```
$ x=0x4a d=74 u=0x1F42E
$ printf '%s\n' ${(#)x} ${(#)d} ${(#u)u}
J
J

$ (){printf '%s\n' ${(#)@}} $x $d $u
J
J
```

For completeness, to get from `J` or  back to `0x4a` or `0x1F42E`, there's the standard

```
$ c1='J' c2=''
$ printf '%#x\n' "'$c1" "'$c2"
0x4a
0x1f42e
```

And also:

```
$ echo $((#c1)) $((#c2)) $((##J)) $((##))
74 128046 74 128046
```

Or:

```
$ echo $(([#16] #c1)) $(([#16] #c2)) $(([##16] #c1)) $(([##16] #c2))
16#4A 16#1F42E 4A 1F42E
$ set -o cbases
$ echo $(([#16] #c1)) $(([#16] #c2))
0x4A 0x1F42E
```

---

<sup>¹ if the locale has no such character, `zsh` falls back to outputting the byte *`n`* & 0xff</sup>

Comment: answer also please how to print this face by 'f0 9f 90 ae' hex code

Comment: @viavad, see [Binary to hexadecimal and decimal in a shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65282)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of numbers to convert, and want to avoid a function call and creating a subshell for each character, you can define the ascii set beforehand:

```
ascii=$(for x in {0..9} {A..F}; do for y in {0..9} {A..F}; do echo -ne "\x$x$y"; done; done)
```

Note that null char is excluded, so every char is offset by 1.

Then use something like this (assumes 1 number per line):

```
while read c; do out+="${ascii:$c-1:1}"; done <<< "$in"
echo "$out"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the conversions using `printf`:

```bsh
printf "%o" "'J" # 112 (oct)
printf "%d" "'J" # 74 (dec)
printf "%x" "'J" # 4a (hex)

printf '\112' # J (oct)
printf "\x$(printf %x 74)" # J (dec, requires double conversion)
printf '\x4a' # J (hex)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [*ANSI-C Quoting* in *Bash Reference Manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), it supports hexadecimal and octal (but not decimal) directly, with no Bash built-ins or external commands required.

```
Js=( $'\x4A' $'\112' )
echo ${Js[@]}
#J J
```