# Print check/cross mark in shell script

Tags: shell-script, echo, unicode

I would like to print a check mark and a cross mark in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 existing"
echo -e "\xE2\x9D\x8C missing"
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: can you check this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311904/how-do-i-print-an-ascii-character-by-different-code-points-in-bash

Comment: Still don't see what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Your two commands work perfectly fine on `mksh` shell, but in bash the first one outputs question mark instead of check.  Might be something to do with bash's implementation of `echo`. You could always switch to `python`'s print as alternative command

Comment: If I am executing the command directly in terminal it is working as expecting. But when executing this commands in a sh-script I get the pure output `\xE2\x9C\x94 exiting`...

Comment: In that case, how are you execiting the file ?  did you put `#!/bin/bash` there or is it `#!/bin/sh` ?Can you try `printf "\xE2\x9C\x94 existing"` instead of `echo` in the script ?

Comment: As you can see in the post I am using `#!/bin/bash` and it doesn't make a difference using `printf` instead of `echo`

Comment: Also, small correction - the echo command that was outputting question mark for me had `\x93`.  My own mistake there. Works fine from script and from interactive shell

Comment: I put this code into a sh-file, give it `chmod +x file.sh` and execute it by `sh file.sh`

Comment: @user3142695 well, there is your problem ! `sh` is a symlink to default shell  , which is different on most systems. For example, on Ubuntu it's a symlink to `/bin/dash` .

Comment: Ok, I am using ubuntu. But changing to `/bin/dash` still keeps the same problem. :-(

Comment: @user3142695  You're not supposed to change to `dash`. It doesn't have support for what you're doing. See my answer. I need to sleep, so we can continue this discussion in about 7 hours

Comment: how do you make it green color

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As revealed by the OP in the comments, they were calling script with `sh file.sh`. Depending on the default shell to which `/bin/sh` is symlinked it might not support unicode characters.

For instance, on Ubuntu , the default shell is `dash`.

```
$ dash
$ printf "\xE2\x9C\x94 missing\n"
\xE2\x9C\x94 missing
$ echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94"
-e \xE2\x9C\x94
```

The reason why it worked when you called the command in interactive shell, is because users interactive shell is by default (on Ubuntu) `/bin/bash`

To properly run the script, you need to either:

- run it as `./file.sh`
- run it as argument to proper shell `bash file.sh`

Alternatively, one could resort to shell-independent methods:

```
# this printf is standalone program, not shell built-in
$ /usr/bin/printf "\xE2\x9C\x94 check mark\n"
✔ check mark

$ python -c 'print "\xE2\x9C\x94 check mark"'
✔ check mark

$ perl -e 'print "\xE2\x9C\x94 check mark"'                                                                              
✔ check mark
```

Comment: in Python you can provide the name of the character and skip the messy/implicit UTF-8 encoding (which I think breaks anyways in Python 3), e.g. `print("\N{HEAVY CHECK MARK}")`

Comment: @NickT  Does look neater. I tested that on couple different Python versions just now, it works in Python 3.7.3 but doesn't seem to work in 2.7.16 or 2.6, where as `python -c 'print "\xE2\x9C\x94 check mark"'` still works on 2.6   I suppose if one is using Python3 that's the way to go - otherwise using the encoding is the best way one's got

Answer (score 12):

Note that `\xE2\x9C\x94` is the UTF-8 encoding of the U+2714 (*heavy check mark*) character.

Those 3 bytes will only be displayed as a check mark if the terminal's character set is UTF-8 (and uses a font that has that character).

For terminal emulators, the charset they use will typically be the one in the locale at the time they were started. Unless you have changed the locale within the shell started in that terminal, you can tell which one it was with:

```
locale charmap
```

Several `printf` implementations including GNU `printf` and the `printf` builtin of `zsh`, `bash` and `lksh` (a more POSIX compatible variant of `mksh` on Debian-based systems at least) support:

```
$ printf '\u2714\u274c\n'
✔❌
```

To print those characters in the correct encoding for the locale's charset (ksh93's `printf` builtin also supports that `\uXXXX` notation but always outputs in UTF-8 regardless of the locale's charset). Shells whose `printf` builtin support it and have an `echo` that expands escape sequences (possibly with `-e`) typically also support `\uXXXX` there.

Now, AFAICT, the only two charsets where those two U+274C and U+2714 characters are available on a typical GNU system are UTF-8 and GB18030. In locales using different charsets, `printf` will not be able to display those characters as they simply don't exist. Depending on the implementation, `printf` will print `\u274C` literally or fail with an error.

Some shells (`zsh` where it originated, `bash`, `ksh93`, `mksh`, FreeBSD `sh`) also support that `\uXXXX` notation in their `$'...'` quotes.

So you can do:

```
echo $'\u2714\u274c'
```

Depending on the shell, those will be expanded to the locale's encoding that was in effect at the time the command was parsed (`bash`) or at the time it was run (`zsh`) or in UTF-8 always (ksh).

POSIXly (portably among Unix-like systems), if you want to print arbitrary sequences of bytes, you'll want to use `printf` and the octal notation.

`\xE2\x9C\x94` (the UTF-8 encoding of U+2714) would be printed on a line portably with:

```
printf '\342\234\224\n'
```

And if you wanted it to be converted to the correct encoding for the locale, that would be:

```
printf '\342\234\224\n' | iconv -f UTF-8
```

POSIX doesn't specify which character encoding may be supported on a system, nor their name, but the above command would typically work on POSIX systems that support the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: can check mark in larger font?

Comment: @alper, try `printf '\e#3\u2714\n\e#4\u2714\n'` in `xterm` or compatible for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Using raw  "cut and paste" Unicode we get a more readable solution:

```
$ echo -e '☑ done\n☒ fail\n☐ to do'
☑ done
☒ fail
☐ to do
```