# Convert a value into a "Binary Number" in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I know of bc:

```
$> var="304"
$> echo "obase=2; $var" | bc
100110000
```

Could it be done in shell (no external call)?

This question:
[Binary to hexadecimal and decimal in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65280/binary-to-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-a-shell-script)
Asks how to convert FROM binary, not TO a binary number.

The answers there deal either with binary byte (as opposed to binary number, i.e.: a base-2 number) using xxd, or some other external tool. So, no, this question is not a duplicate of that.

Comment: You should read the [answer from Stéphane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65290/38906), it contain all things you want.

Comment: Explained in the question, but it must be obvious that all answers in the question linked used external commands. None used a shell script. That is something not done before.

Comment: All solution in that answer using *shell script*, it's only not POSIX. It can be better if you can stick your solution with that question.

Comment: That answer you link has very good points for the question asked there. And solves some parts of the problem only for ksh and/or zsh. There is no solution usable in bash, for example. Even worse, there is no attempt to make a portable solution.

Comment: Strictly speaking, even the use of `echo` may introduce an "external call".

Answer (score 8):

In bash:

```
toBinary(){
    local n bits sign=''
    (($1<0)) && sign=-
    for (( n=$sign$1 ; n>0 ; n >>= 1 )); do bits=$((n&1))$bits; done
    printf "%s\n" "$sign${bits-0}"
}
```

Use:

```
$> toBinary 304
100110000
```

Or more POSIX_ly:

```
toBinaryPOSIX(){
    n=$(($1))
    bits=""
    sign=""
    if [ "$n" -lt 0 ]; then
        sign=- n=$((-n))
    fi
    while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
        bits="$(( n&1 ))$bits";
        : $(( n >>= 1 ))
    done
    printf "%s\n" "$sign${bits:-0}"
}
```

Use:

```
$> toBinaryPOSIX 304
100110000
```

If Value is hex:

```
$> toBinaryPOSIX 0x63
1100011
```

Comment: `local` is not in POSIX.

Comment: It does not work for negative numbers: Binary representation of `-1` is `11111 ... 111`, not `-1`.

Answer (score 8):

`perl` is good tool for this job:

```
$ var="304"
$ perl -e 'printf "%b\n",'$var
100110000
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses builtins only to convert number to binary form:

```
#! /bin/sh

E=[24680] # even nums
O=[13579] # odd  nums

lookuptbl() {
   case $1 in
      $E[01]* ) echo 0 ;; $E[23]* ) echo 1 ;;
      $E[45]* ) echo 2 ;; $E[67]* ) echo 3 ;;
      $E[89]* ) echo 4 ;; $O[01]* ) echo 5 ;;
      $O[23]* ) echo 6 ;; $O[45]* ) echo 7 ;;
      $O[67]* ) echo 8 ;; $O[89]* ) echo 9 ;;
   esac
}

divby2() {
   set -- "0$1"

   while case $1 in ? ) break ;; esac; do
      set -- "${1#?}" "${2-}$(lookuptbl "$1")"
   done

   echo $2
}

dec2bin() {
   case $1 in *[!0]* ) :;; * ) echo 0; return ;; esac

   while :
   do
      case $1 in *[!0]* ) :;; * ) break;; esac
      case $1 in
         *$E ) set -- "$(divby2 "$1")" "0${2-}" ;;
         *$O ) set -- "$(divby2 "$1")" "1${2-}" ;;
      esac
   done

   echo "$2"
}

# And then... (assuming pure number given from command line)
num=${1:-304}
dec2bin "$num"
```

## result

```
100110000
```

Answer (score 2):

With `ksh` or `zsh`:

```
$ typeset -i2 n=304
$ echo "$n"
2#100110000
$ echo "${n#*#}"
100110000
```

With `zsh`:

```
$ echo $(([##2]304))
100110000
```

With `ksh93`:

```
$ printf '%..2d\n' 304
100110000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the POSIX Awk [stdlib library](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib):

```
$ awklib 'BEGIN {print base_conv(304, 10, 2)}'
100110000
```

Or:

```
$ awklib 'BEGIN {print base_conv(ARGV[1], 10, 2)}' 304
100110000
```